# Ng2-Redux not displaying object property in view

Tags: angular, redux

I have a company object that is not displaying any value in my view. When I attached subscribe method to the instance everything correctly displays in the console.

View:

```
<h2>{{scopedCompany$.name | async}}</h2>
<h2 *ngFor="let company of companies$ | async">{{company.name}}</h2>
```

Component:

```
@select('scopedCompany') scopedCompany$: Observable<Company>;
@select('companies') companies$: Observable<Company[]>;

constructor(
    private securityService: OidcSecurityService,
    private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>,
    private navigation: NavigationService
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.scopedCompany$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
}
```

app-module:

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>) {
    ngRedux.provideStore(store);
  }
}


 export interface IAppState {
    companies: Company[];
    scopedCompany: Company;
 }
```

The array of companies displays the name property but the scopedCompany does not.

Comment: What if you remove the `.subscribe`?

Comment: it changes nothing. I just added that to see if the state was actually being updated